# Time out error while purging in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

In the process of purging, while doing re-indexing we are getting timeout errors. I increased read_request_timeout. I doubled it… but still getting the same errors

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the timeouts in Cassandra is almost never the right action. The timeouts are in place to prevent nodes from getting overloaded by expensive queries.

When you increase the timeouts, you're not solving the underlying problem but just delaying it and creating more problems for yourself later on. You need to identify the cause of the timeouts and address it.

As a side note, you haven't provided enough information for anyone to be able to give you a meaningful answer. You need to provide details of what you're doing, what you've tried, as well as full error messages + the full stack trace. Terms like "purging" and "re-indexing" are meaningless without the information behind them. Cheers!